# Is there a way to run manipulations on partitioned spark datasets in parallel?

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have a list of datasets that I want to partition by a particular key that is common to all my datasets and then run some joins/grouping which is same for all the partitioned datasets.

I am trying to design the algorithm in such a way that i use Spark's partitionBy to create partition by a particular key.

Now, one way is to run the operations on each partition in a loop but that's not efficient.

I wanted to see if I have manually partitioned data, can I run operations on these datasets in parallel.

I have just started learning Spark so forgive me if its a naive question.

Consider a dataset of customer Ids and their behavioral data like browsing/clicks etc. in different datasets. Say one for browse, another for clicks. First I am thinking of partitioning my data by Customer Ids and then for each partition(customer), join on some attribute say browser or device to see how each customer behaves. So basically, its like a nested parallelization.

Is that even possible in Spark ? Is there something obvious I am missing ? Some documentation I can refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this  -**

```
1. Create test dataset (Totol Record = 70000+) to perform parallel operation on each 

scala> ds.count
res137: Long = 70008

scala> ds.columns
res124: Array[String] = Array(awards, country)

2. Assume partition column as "country".

scala> ds.select("country").distinct.show(false)
+-------+
|country|
+-------+
|CANADA |
|CHINA  |
|USA    |
|EUROPE |
|UK     |
|RUSSIA |
|INDIA  |
+-------+

3. Get sum of records for each country [ **Without parallel process for each partition**]

scala> val countries = ds.select("country").distinct.collect
countries: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([CANADA], [CHINA], [USA], [EUROPE], [UK], [RUSSIA], [INDIA])

scala> val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
startTime: Long = 1562047887130

scala> countries.foreach(country => ds.filter(ds("country") === country(0)).groupBy("country").count.show(false))
+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|CANADA |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|CHINA  |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|USA    |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|EUROPE |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|UK     |10002|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|RUSSIA |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|INDIA  |10001|
+-------+-----+


scala> val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
endTime: Long = 1562047896088

scala> println(s"Total Execution Time :  ${(endTime - startTime) / 1000} Seconds")
Total Execution Time :  **8 Seconds**

4. Get sum of records for each country [ **With parallel process for each partition**]

scala> val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
startTime: Long = 1562048057431

scala> countries.par.foreach(country => ds.filter(ds("country") === country(0)).groupBy("country").count.show(false))

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|INDIA  |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|CANADA |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|RUSSIA |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|USA    |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|UK     |10002|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|CHINA  |10001|
+-------+-----+

+-------+-----+
|country|count|
+-------+-----+
|EUROPE |10001|
+-------+-----+


scala> val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
endTime: Long = 1562048060273

scala> println(s"Total Execution Time :  ${(endTime - startTime) / 1000} Seconds")
Total Execution Time :  **2 Seconds**
```

**Result :-**

```
With    parallel process on each partition, it took ~ **2 Seconds**
Without parallel process on each partition, it took ~ **8 Seconds**
```

I tested to check the number of records for each country, you can perform any process e.g. writing to hive table or hdfs file, etc.

**Hope this is helpful**.